# how to define multi select element in zend framework2?

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2, multi-select

i need to show multi select element in form. i use this:

```
        $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'services',
        'attributes' =>  array(
            'id' => 'state',
            'multiple'=>true,
            'options' => array(
                'Web Design'=>'Web Design',                    
                'Web Software'=>'Web Software',
                'IT Solutions'=>'IT Solutions',
                'SEO'=>'SEO',                    
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Services',
        ),
    ));
```

and define validator in my model:

```
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'services',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'NotEmpty',
                ),
            ),
        )));
```

but when i validate form with $form->isValid() in my controller, it return false.
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'services',
        'required' => false,
        'allowEmpty' => true
    )));
```